# Pandas Dataframe: assigning a new column based comparing each value of one column to all the values of another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to assign a new column to a Pandas by finding a key value which corresponds to the minimum difference between a value of a column (x) and any value of another column (y).
Example:

```
     key       x        y      
0      1       6        2
1      3       9        4
2      5       7        7
3      7       2        10
```

row 0 has an x value of 6. This is closest to the y value of row 2 which is 7. Thus the corresponding value that I want to get for this row would be 5, the key of row 2.
Expected result:

```
     key       x        y      result
0      1       6        2      5
1      3       9        4      7
2      5       7        7      5
3      7       2        10     1
```

I've thought about using

```
import np as numpy
import pandas as pd

result = []
for x in df["x"]:
     diffs = abs(df.y - x)
     min_diff = diffs.index(min(diffs))
     result.append(min_diff)
df["result"] = result
```

But this requires creating temporary lists and requires running through the second column multiple times. Is there a pythonic workaround to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, no temporaries

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: df['key'][(df['y']-row['x']).abs().argmin()], axis=1)
```

output

```
   key  x   y   result
0   1   6   2   5
1   3   9   4   7
2   5   7   7   5
3   7   2   10  1
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. The idea of applying the column to each row like that did not cross my mind. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is a little bit more involved than the solution you were thinking of using, but you were on the right track.

Looping through the rows seemed like the best solution, and then finding the difference between x on each row and the whole of the y column. We have to use `abs()` to neutralise any negative values before we can get the minimum. Then, get the index of the lowest difference. Then we can easily get the key using the index. Store this in a list and finally create the new column.

```
results = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    # get the absolute value of the differences
    diffs = abs(row.x - df.y)
    
    # get the index of the minimum difference
    idxmin = diffs.idxmin()

    # get the value of key using the index
    key = df['key'][idxmin]

    results.append(key)

df['results'] = results
```

My output:

```
   key  x   y  results
0    1  6   2        5
1    3  9   4        7
2    5  7   7        5
3    7  2  10        1
```